# Convert a PDF to PDF/A using IText 7?

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I need to convert a PDF file as a stream (1.7) to PDFA/3. The original file has the fonts and images already embedded.

So far I did:

```
var output = new MemoryStream();
var reader = new PdfReader(stream);
var writer = new PdfWriter(output);

Stream s = new FileStream("sRGB Color Space Profile.icm", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var intent = new PdfOutputIntent("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", s);

var pdfA = new PdfADocument(writer, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_3A, intent);

//Setting some required parameters
pdfA.SetTagged();
pdfA.GetCatalog().SetLang(new PdfString("en-US"));
pdfA.GetCatalog().SetViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().SetDisplayDocTitle(true));

PdfDocumentInfo info = pdfA.GetDocumentInfo();
info.SetTitle("test pdf/a");
```

However I got stuck on how to copy from the input stream to the writer and return the pdf/a as a stream.

Furthermore, can I use iText to perform a conformance text on the output?

Any ideas?

Comment: My mother once made carrot soup. She cut the carrots in pieces and mixed them. However, my father had promised his neighbor those carrots. How can my father extract the original carrots from the carrot soup my mother made? The answer is: he can't. That is also the answer to your question, because you're trying to do something similar. Someone created a PDF from content that was structured. However, all structure went lost in the process. Now you want to recreate the lost structure (`PDF_A_3A`). A human being might be able to do that. A machine can't until we reach singularity.

Comment: It's a different story if you replace the `A` with a `B`: `PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_3B`.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I understand. I changed it to B. I also added: `source.CopyPagesTo(1, source.GetNumberOfPages(), target);` which I assume copies the pages including all their related objects as is. Is this enough?